# Add a pagination-like value inside an object

Tags: javascript

I need to add a page:1 inside the `sampledata`. Please note that the `sampledata` is fixed and I need to add another value `page:1` after each `array`.

```
var sampledata = [ 
  { id:1, title:'Title 1'},
  { id:2, title:'Title 2'},
  { id:3, title:'Title 3'},
  { id:4, title:'Title 4'},
  { id:5, title:'Title 5'},
  { id:6, title:'Title 6'}
];
```

I created a loop to add the page and its value.

```
for( var a = 0; a < sampledata.length; a++ ){
  sampledata[a].page = 1;
}
```

Now, the `sampledata` prints like this:

```
var sampledata = [ 
  { id:1, title:'Title 1', page:1},
  { id:2, title:'Title 2', page:1},
  { id:3, title:'Title 3', page:1},
  { id:4, title:'Title 4', page:1},
  { id:5, title:'Title 5', page:1},
  { id:6, title:'Title 6', page:1}
];
```

How can I achieve to output `sampledata` with page the value like below?

```
var sampledata = [ 
  { id:1, title:'Title 1', page:1},
  { id:2, title:'Title 2', page:1},
  { id:3, title:'Title 3', page:2},
  { id:4, title:'Title 4', page:2},
  { id:5, title:'Title 5', page:3},
  { id:6, title:'Title 6', page:3}
];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take the index and take the integer value of the division by two (or any other value) and add one for starting page values with one instead of zero.

```js
var data = [{ id: 1, title: 'Title 1'}, { id: 2, title: 'Title 2'}, { id: 3, title: 'Title 3'}, { id: 4, title: 'Title 4'}, { id: 5, title: 'Title 5'}, { id: 6, title: 'Title 6'}],
    itemsPerPage = 2,
    result = data.map((o, i) => Object.assign({}, o, { page: Math.floor(i / itemsPerPage) + 1 }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This was quick! Just one more question how can I change to 10 instead of 2?

Comment: where is `2` and where do you want `10`?

Comment: I'm sorry it wasn't clear. I mean the number of array with the page value of 1 is 2. `page:1` 
How can I change the 10 arrays to have `page:1` if I have a total of 100?

Comment: you could change `itemsPerPage` with the wanted items.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to add a `page` property based on the index and a `pageSize`, you can use [`Math.floor()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) like this:

```js
var sampledata = [{ id: 1, title: 'Title 1'}, { id: 2, title: 'Title 2'}, { id: 3, title: 'Title 3'}, { id: 4, title: 'Title 4'}, { id: 5, title: 'Title 5'}, { id: 6, title: 'Title 6'}];

var pageSize = 2; // change to whatever you need

sampledata.forEach((o, i) => o.page = 1 + Math.floor(i/pageSize))

console.log(sampledata)
```